# C++ TCP server-client little issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winapi, tcp

I have a TCP server and client. Server code part:

```
/*int Main()*/
while(1)
{
    client_socket = accept (my_socket, (sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addrlen);


    nclients++;

    HOSTENT *my_host;
    my_host = gethostbyaddr((char *)&client_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, 4, AF_INET);
    htons(client_addr.sin_port));
    printf("Client name: %s\n", (my_host) ? my_host->h_name : "");
    printf("Client IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr)); //here is client IP

    PRINTNUSERS;
    DWORD threadID;
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, ClientFunc, &client_socket, NULL, &threadID);
}
```

For each new client i want to create a new thread to handle it

```
DWORD WINAPI ClientFunc(LPVOID client_socket)
{
SOCKET Thread_sock;
Thread_sock = ((SOCKET *)client_socket)[0];
SOCKADDR_IN Thread_addr;   //how can i connect thread IP with client IP
/*send(), recv() operations*/
}
```

I want to print Client IP in my thread. 
How do i get Client IP address locating in `Thread_addr.sin_addr`structure. I have my Client IP address located on my `int main()`function, but how to connect it with thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one argument to thread function in WINApi. And you have already INCORRECTLY used it for your socket - you are passing an address of local variable to the thread. By the time your thread is executing, this local variable will be lost, and something completely different will be living at this address. Following solutions are available:

- Prefferred solution. Ditch WinApi threads (which you are using incorrectly, btw. C++ programms should not use CreateThread, but instead beginthreadex_. Use C++ thread functions instead. This way you will get a way to pass arguments to thread function like you do for any other function, and you will not have to pass addresses (which you still will not be able to do!), or references.
- Worse solution. Pack all your arguments into the struct, allocate the struct on the heap and pass address of this struct. In the thread function unpack arguments and delete the struct.

Comment: I will try to use std::thread and pass 2 agruments to thread (socket and IP address).

Comment: Uhh, i dont understand. Did u say, that there is no way i pass address to thread?

Comment: @N.Zazulin, you should not pass addresses of local variables to the threads. Regardless of which management system you use for your threads, the address will mean nothing by the time the thread starts to execute - unless, of course, you are waiting for the thread to complete before leaving current scope. The drawback of native threads is that the ONLY thing they can receive is an address! So in order to pass anything to them, you need to allocate structure on the heap (using new, for instance) and pass the address of this structure. C++ threads do not have this limitation.

Comment: You can pass objects by value to those.